# Removing user profile junction point

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles, ntfs-junction, directory-junction

Initial state:
My user account profile (on my Windows 10 system)
was on `C:\Users\<my account>`. 
Due to partition size limitations,
I created a folder on `E:\Users\<my account>`
and created a junction point (SYMLINKD)
so that `C:\Users\<my account>`
points to `E:\users\<my account>`.

Desired state:
Remove the SYMLINK so that the folder *`<my account>`* is
a real folder on `C:\Users\`
and not pointing to `E:\Users\<my account>`.

I know the commands to use for Windows 10 to remove a junction point,
in general. 
I am worried about applying them to a user profile directory. 
I am especially worried about `ntuser.dat`. 
I have a backup of all the files but
I'm not sure how removing the link will impact the user profile.

Comment: I'm a Linux user mostly. I *guess* there is some general way to remove a junction point in Windows. You should find this way as a part of your research effort. Is there any problem when you just try? Or is there any reason you think this general way would break the OS or your account?

Comment: If it were linux, I wouldn't be apprehensive. I know the specific commands to use for Windows 10 to remove the juntion point. However in this case I am afraid of corrupting my user profile. I especially worried about ntuser.dat.

Comment: (1) You could make this question better by stating the commands that you believe you should use.  (2) Do a “dry run”. Create another (dummy, disposable) account. Migrate it to `E:` following the procedure you used for your real account (I hope you kept a record of those commands), then try to migrate it back and see what happens. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3a) In any case, you should probably not migrate your account back *while logged in to your account.*  Create a second administrator account and use it.  (3b) Actually, it might be interesting to login as yourself and as the second administrator account *concurrently* (and do the work from the second session).  Then again, you might not be allowed to manipulate the profile of your primary account while it is in use.